# Updating max flow in a Control Flow Graph using Ford Fulkerson?

Tags: algorithm, ford-fulkerson

I'm given a Control Flow Graph with natural numbers representing edge capacites and a max flow found by running Ford Fulkerson. I'm asked to find a quick algorithm to update the max flow if the following occurs:
1. one edge e is changed s.t. its capacity grows by 1
2. one edge e is changed s.t. its capacity diminishes by 1

For the first scenario, an a given edge e=(u,v), place another edge , e'=(u,v) in the graph s.t. e' has a capacity of 1. Then run FF again on the graph, and by definition of FF, it will find another path if such exists from s to t and update the max flow.

My question is this: Why is this different than just running FF with the original graph, but changing the capacity of e to e+1?

I would also appreciate any help or guidance on 2. as I have no idea where to go with that scenario.